# Clicking on image to replace with iframe src is passing in the wrong data-attribute

Tags: jquery, this, parent, replacewith

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rg2LLvy1/  It's almost working, however clicking on either image passes in the first video's data-video attribute, instead of passing in the "correct" data-video associated for each image. E.g. If you click on the Cats video, the iframe plays the Soccer video. I think I'm missing a 'this' somewhere? Thank you!

```
$('img.img-youtube').parent().click(function(){
video = '<iframe src="'+ $('img.img-youtube').attr('data-video') +'"></iframe>';
    $(this).parent().replaceWith(video);
});
```

Comment: Now it works:
https://jsfiddle.net/rg2LLvy1/1/

Comment: Thanks @Offir Pe'er ! If you leave this as a separate reply  I could mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working [Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rg2LLvy1/1/).

```
$('img.img-youtube').parent().click(function(){
    video = '<iframe src="'+ $(this).find('img.img-youtube').data('video') +'"></iframe>';
    $(this).parent().replaceWith(video);
});
```

The problem was that your selector `$('img.img-youtube').attr('data-video')` gave you the first value because you had 2 results for this selector and that's why you had to add a `this` so it will be specific to the image you clicked on.

Also when using JQuery you can use `data selector` instead of `attr('data-video')` , it just makes life easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img.img-youtube').parent().click(function(e){
console.log($(this).find("img").attr('data-video'));
    video = '<iframe src="'+ $(this).find("img").attr('data-video') +'"></iframe>';
    $(this).parent().replaceWith(video);
});
```